# Covariance and MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

There is a class Shape from him inherited triangle, ellipse, etc. 
Question.
How can I change figure in the View. When I change figures in ViewModel

```
public class MainViewModel : NotificationObject
{
    private Shape shape;

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        Shape = new Ellipse;
        ChangeCurrentShapeCommand = new DelegateCommand(ChangeCurrentShape);
    }

    public Shape Shape
    {
        get
        {
            return this.shape;
        }
        set
        {
            this.shape = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.Shape);
        }
    }

    public DelegateCommand ChangeCurrentShapeCommand { get; set; }

    private void ChangeCurrentShape()
    {
        Shape = new Triangle;
    }
}
```

When I call ChangeCurrentShapeCommand on the screen Ellipses changed to Triangle.

Answer (score 2):

1)Bind to `Shape` from view

2)Define [Data Templates](http://drwpf.com/blog/category/data-templates/) for each shape type(triangle,ellipse,etc)